# Unable to scan char variable after scanning int in C

Tags: c

I am having problem scanning char variable , my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() 
{
clrscr();
int a;
float b;
char c;

printf("Enter value for int variable \n");
scanf("%d",&a);

printf("Enter value for float variable \n");
scanf("%f",&b);

printf("Enter value for char variable \n");
scanf("%c",&c); //scanning is automatically skipped !!! 

getch();
}
```

Please tell me , why is this happening and what can i do to solve it !

Comment: Trailing new line, several duplicates on SO

Comment: I would add `'\n'` at the end of every string passed to `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the stored <kbd>enter</kbd> key press [considered as character input]. use one `getch();` before the third `scanf()`.

alternatively, use `(scanf(" %c",&c);)` [mind the space before `%c`] which will get rid of any number of whitespace [buffered] character present before actual input.